# Map app in iphone 4.1

Tags: iphone, ipad, google-maps, ios4, core-location

I ran map application(built in) in iphone 4.1.when i give, for example "shops in new york", it shows in map with annotations of all shops.i hope it handles xml file through google URL.anybody knows that url to implement in my aplication?Needs URL for csv response or xml response with multiple latitude and longitiude values, u have given direct URL.

Answer (score 0):

'Shops in New York' seems to be a predefined query that Google Maps accepts.

You can issue within a standard browser using

http://maps.google.com/maps?q="shops in new york"

I'm not sure if this is the problem you are trying to solve, however - feel free to provide some more detail and we'll see if we can figure it out.

- Gemma

Comment: hi i asked URL  for csv response or xml response with multiple latitude and longitiude values, u have given direct URL.

Comment: Right, in that case, KML seems to be what you are looking for - this link should help you (http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/whatiskml.html). You will need to a) Create a KML file with the annotations you require, b) Place it on a webserver c) access the file in the browser. It should automatically be overlaid on top of a Google Map.

Comment: Additionally, you can test out your KML as you are building it using something like this online editor : http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/interactive/index.html